# How to use statistical function for the entire array column in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, statistics

I am a novice to Ruby programming and can't find an answer to the following question. Is there a single command to calculate standard deviation for the entire array column arr[].friends?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'descriptive_statistics'
class MyList < Struct.new(:id, :name,:friends)
end
arr = Array.new
f = File.open("test-comma.txt", "r")
f.each_line { |line| words = line.split(',')
   p = MyList.new
   p.id=words[0]
   p.name=words[1]
   p.friends=words[2]
   arr.push(p)
   }
f.close
```

All examples I am able to find on the Internet offer 1-dimensional arrays (vectors). And it does not make any sense to use *inject* since there are pre-built statistical functions in the gem "descriptive_statistics".

Comment: The standard deviation of which value do you want to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

`descriptive_statistics` extends `Enumerable` so you can do:

```
arr.collect{|p| p.friends}.standard_deviation
```

This is of course provided p.friends is a number